# Filtering a table with condition involving another table in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I tried to create a measure to calculate all clicks made by users registered within the last 15 days

```
NewUserClicks = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(
            DISTINCT('v_clicks'[unique_click_id])
        ),
        FILTER(
            ALL('v_user'),
            'v_user'[date_created_at] >= MIN('calendar'[Date]) - 15 && 'v_user'[date_created_at] <= MAX('calendar'[Date])
        ),
        USERELATIONSHIP('v_clicks'[unique_user_id], 'v_user'[unique_user_id])
    )
```

However, this produces numbers bigger than simply counting 'v_clicks'[unique_click_id] without any filter. I'm puzzled by this behaviour. I'm aware the 'ALL' in the filter clause has something to do with it, but I'm not sure how.

Does anyone have any insight?

Update:
Data model
[image]

Relationships
[image]

Edit:
Without any filter
[image]

With filter:
[image]

Comment: Those numbers look ok. For each date range it is including data from the previous 15 days as well. Is there an issue?

Comment: How could clicks from New users be more than clicks from all users?

Comment: Apologies - misunderstood your ask - pls ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will need to see your data model but giving it a go in the dark. Try:

```
NewUserClicks = 
  var minD = MIN('calendar'[Date])
  var maxD = MAX('calendar'[Date])

  var users =
    CALCULATEDTABLE(
      DISTINCT('v_user'[unique_user_id]),
      REMOVEFILTERS('calendar'),
      'v_user'[date_created_at] >= minD - 15 && 
      'v_user'[date_created_at] <= maxD
    )

  return
    CALCULATE(
      DISTINCTCOUNT('v_clicks'[unique_click_id]),
      'v_clicks'[unique_user_id] IN users 
   )
```

Comment: Produces exactly the same result as before

Comment: Could you update your question with a screen grab of your data model, showing the three tables with their relationships. Updated answer above, give it a go.

Comment: Updated. Results are same as before

Comment: Both users and clicks have an active relationship with calendar; is that the problem?

Comment: Try the now, updated.

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Are you sure the numbers are wrong? Which visual are you using? Can you share a screen grab of the report or even share sample PBIX?

Comment: Column charts. Updated my OP with screen shots

Comment: Apologies, I miss understood what you are wanting. Try it now, should be good.

Comment: Yes, It matches the SQL query numbers now.  Something so simple in SQL is so complicated in DAX. Thank you very much

Comment: Awesome, please help mark the answer as Accepted for the benefit of all (the check mark below the voting buttons).